# Showing the Monge-Ampere equation is elliptic

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations

I have a question about my books definition of ellipticy on how it relates to the Monge-Ampere equation in $\mathbb R^2$.

> The Monge-Ampere equation is as follows. Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $ \mathbb R^2=\{x=(x_1,x_2)\}$ and let $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ satisfy $u_{x_1x_1}(x)u_{x_2x_2}(x)-u^2_{x_1x_2}(x)-f(x)=0$ where $f>0$ in $\Omega$ and the Hessian of $u$ is positive definite ($u$ is convex).

The definition of ellipticy given in my book is as follows:

> Consider a general differential equation $F[u]=F(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))=0$ where $F:S:=\Omega \times \mathbb R \times \mathbb R^d \times S(d,\mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$ where $S(d,\mathbb R)$ is the space of real symmetric $d\times d$ matricies. Elements of $ S$ are written as $(x,z,p,r)$ where $p=(p_1,...,p_d)$ and $r=(r_{ij})_{1\le i,j \le d}$ The differential equation $F[u]$ is said to be elliptic at $u$ if $\left( \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))\right)_{1 \le i,j \le d} $ is positive definite.

So using this definition how do we compute $ \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x)) $ for each pair of $(i,j)$? We can see that $r_{i,j}=u_{x_ixj}$ so for example does $$ \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{1,1}}(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x)) = \dfrac{\partial}{u_{x_1x_1}}\left(u_{x_1x_1}(x)u_{x_2x_2}(x)-u^2_{x_1x_2}(x)-f(x)\right)=u_{x_2x_2}(x) $$ 
 Then by this logic $\left( \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}(x,u(x),Du(x),D^2u(x))\right)_{1 \le i,j \le d}= \begin{bmatrix}
    u_{x_2x_2}       & -2u_{x_1x_2}  \\
    -2u_{x_1x_2}      & u_{x_1x_1}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$ but if this is correct why is this matrix positive definite? Also where does the condition of $f>0$ come into play.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Check your Monge-Ampere equation again.  It should be $\det D^2u - f=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks I changed it, but my question is still the same, do you now if the way im calculating $\frac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}$ is correct?

Comment: Unfortunately your book suppressed an important detail -- since you are dealing with symmetric matrices, as basis $r_{i,j}$ is only for $i\geq j$ (say) and to get the $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq d}$ (as opposed to $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}\right)_{1\leq i\leq j\leq d}$) you need to spread that evenly across the diagonal.  So you end up with basically $D^2u$ as the linearization.

Comment: So $D^2u$ needs to be positive-definite for ellipticity (which you have assumed).  Of course, $D^2u$ positive-definite implies $\det D^2u>0$ and for a solution $u$ of MA, this is $f>0$.

Comment: @user10354138 could you further explain that? So is what I put for $\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}\right)$ wrong?

Comment: Well, depends on what you mean by $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}\right)$.  If you mean the vector $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}\right)_{1\leq i\leq j\leq d}$ as derivative in the $S(d,\mathbb{R})$ component then it is correct.  If you want linearization matrix $\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial r_{i,j}}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq d}$ of top-order derivative terms then the off-diagonal entries are off by the factor of 2.

Comment: @user10354138 So it would be this? $\begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{u_{x_2x_2}}{2}       & -2u_{x_1x_2}  \\
    -2u_{x_1x_2}      & \frac{u_{x_1x_1}}{2}  \\
\end{bmatrix}$ and if so why is this going to be positive definite if $D^2u$ is positive definite?

Comment: No, it should be $$\begin{pmatrix}u_{,22} & -u_{,12}\\ -u_{,12} & u_{,11}\end{pmatrix}$$.  This is positive-definite because it is the same as the Hessian $D^2u$ with a change of basis $(e_1,e_2)\to.(-e_2,e_1)$.

Answer (score 1):

@user10354138's last comment is right. I think it is not helpful to write $r_{ij}=u_{x_ix_j}$ at first. Write
$F[A] = a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21}$,
then the matrix:
$$
F^{ij} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial a_{ij}} = \begin{pmatrix}a_{22} & -a_{21}\\ -a_{12} & a_{,11}\end{pmatrix}$$.

This is positive definite when its evaluated at $D^2u$, provided $u$ is smooth and  convex.

Alternatively, regardless of the dimension you can use the derivative of the determinant:
$$\frac{d}{dt} [detA(t)]=\det A(t) \cdot \mbox{trace}\left[A^{-1}(t)\cdot \frac{d}{dt} A(t)\right]$$.

Answer (score 0):

The Monge-Ampere equation is not elliptic in general. You need to assume that the solution $u$ is convex. Take a look at wikipedia [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monge%E2%80%93Amp%C3%A8re_equation) or at the review paper [De-Phillipis-Figalli](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2014-51-04/S0273-0979-2014-01459-4/S0273-0979-2014-01459-4.pdf)

Comment: His book defines MA as the elliptic MA (per first blockquote).

Comment: Yes but if you look at  user10354138's last message, you see that to have ellipticity you need $D^2u$ to be positive definite, which implies that $u$ is convex.